# Can't boot Ubuntu 16.04 with nvidia GTX 1070 card

Tags: boot, nvidia, asus, raid

I can't boot my system at all with this card plugged in. I dont have any nvidia drivers installed anymore either. All I want is to be able to have the card plugged in so that I can pass it through to a windows VM.

As it is currently, I can't even boot into recovery mode.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your CPU/Motherboard/BIOS support IOMMU?

Comment: Yes it does. I actually figured out the issue. My motherboard is an ASUS Z9PE-D16/2L and it has this WHEA (Windows Hardware Error Architecture ) setting in its bios. This was causing some kind of PCI interrupt lock up on boot when I had the 1070 installed (an asus GTX 1070) which wasn't happening when I my GTX 970 and/or GTX 280 plugged in. I got my machine in a functioning state by disabling WHEA in the bios. Am able to play DOOM (2016) at 60fps on a 2560x1440 monitor through a windows VM with iommu passthrough now.

Comment: Excellent!  I'd suggest posting that as an answer to your own question, and accepting it!  That way, anyone who has similar issues can see what happened, and how you fixed it! :)